# Getting parent of wrapInstance causes window to break

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I've been using a modified version of [this](https://gist.github.com/liorbenhorin/69da10ec6f22c6d7b92deefdb4a4f475) code to wrap a Qt window inside Maya's own `workspaceControl`. To get the outside level of the widget to query geometry, size, move, etc, I actually need to do `self.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()`, since it's wrapped within quite a lot of widgets.

I've been working around one or two various issues caused by doing that, but today I hit something a bit more vital and decided to find exactly what the cause is.

Through testing I've narrowed down the code as much as possible, and I've found it's when attempting to get the parent of `shiboken2.wrapInstance`. Attempting to create the window after that comes up with an error saying `RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget) already deleted.`.

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omUI
import pymel.core as pm
import shiboken2
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

win_id = 'test'
#Delete existing window
if pm.workspaceControl(win_id, exists=True):
    pm.deleteUI(win_id)

#Create window and setup wrapper
pm.workspaceControl(win_id)
c_pointer = omUI.MQtUtil.findControl(win_id)
parent_wrap = shiboken2.wrapInstance(int(c_pointer), QtWidgets.QWidget)
print parent_wrap.parent()

#Create actual window
#This will error if parent_wrap.parent() was called
win = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(parent_object)
```

How could I get the parent of the wrap instance without causing issues? I assume it's something to do with unreferencing things from memory prematurely, but I'm not sure how I could go about fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix that is kinda dirty but seems to work reliably so far.

So to start with I found if you create two instances of the above `parent_wrap`, and get the parent before you create the second one, it's possible to pass into the window separately without causing issues. It works up until the point the window is docked/detached, but that deletes the old parents and provides new ones, so the old pointer is no longer valid.

It seemed that providing this parent before the window being initialised allowed me to then regerate it with `self.parent().parent()....` without breaking the code.

It needs to be updated if the state has changed (floating/docked), and whenever a `RuntimeError` occurs, but as it's not going to be a huge hit in performance, for simplicity I'm just regenerating it each time it is needed.

To override a function, like `move` for example, this would be how to use it:

```
def move(self, x, y):
    if self.dockable:
        return self._parent_override().move(x, y)
    return QtWidgets.QMainWindow.move(self, x, y)
```

And this is the override class to solve the issue:

```
def _parent_override(self, create=True):
    #Determine if it's a new window, we need to get the C++ pointer again
    if not hasattr(self, '__temp_parent'):
        base = qt_get_window(self.ID)
    else:
        base = self.parent()

    #Get the correct parent level
    if pm.workspaceControl(self.ID, query=True, floating=True):
        parent = base.parent().parent().parent().parent()
    else:
        parent = base.parent().parent()

    #Even though this attribute is never used,
    #PySide2 is dumb and deletes the parent if it's not set
    self.__temp_parent = parent
    return parent
```